# Expanding (x+y)**n binomials for any n value

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program for my daughter which use as entrance the n coefficient of the polynomial (with integer values for n between 1 and 25) and returns the corresponding expanded polynomial.

For example, for 4 as entrance, it should give as output

> `x**4 + 4*x**3 + 6*x**2*y**2 + 4*x*y**3 + y**4`.

For this, I need to define  a function to calculate te binomial  coeffcients, and then another function that receives a character representing a variable and the n value, giving as output the chain that represents the variable raised to the power of n.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`sympy`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy#installation)

```
import sympy
x, y = sympy.symbols("x y")
formula = (x + y) ** 4
print(formula.expand())

formula = (x + y) ** 5
print(formula.expand())
```

**Output:**

```
x**4 + 4*x**3*y + 6*x**2*y**2 + 4*x*y**3 + y**4
x**5 + 5*x**4*y + 10*x**3*y**2 + 10*x**2*y**3 + 5*x*y**4 + y**5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Pascal's Triangle for the binomial expansion. It represents the coefficients of the expansion.

```
         1
        1 1
       1 2 1
      1 3 3 1
     1 4 6 4 1
```

and so on. n is the power, and k is the index of entry on that line in Pascals triangle. Calling it in a loop should give the expansion  coefficients.

```
int binomial_coeef(int n, int k) 
{ 
    int res = 1; 
    if (k > n - k) 
    k = n - k; 
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) 
    { 
        res *= (n - i); 
        res /= (i + 1); 
    } 
      
    return res; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict the coefficients of x and y to 1, then this should work:

```
def binomial_theorem(power):
    power = int(power)
    coefficients = get_coefficients(power)
    x_powers, y_powers = get_powers(power)
    terms = [f'{n}x**{p_x}y**{p_y}' for (n, p_x, p_y) in zip(coefficients, x_powers, y_powers)]
    expansion = ' + '.join(terms)
    return expansion

def get_powers(power):
    x_powers = [x for x in range(power, -1, -1)]
    y_powers = [y for y in range(power+1)]
    return x_powers, y_powers

def get_coefficients(power):
    coefficients = [choose(power, b) for b in range(power+1)]
    return coefficients

def choose(n, p):
    assert n >= p
    coefficient = factorial(n)/(factorial(p)*factorial(n-p))
    return coefficient
    
def factorial(x):
    factorial = 1
    if int(x) >= 1:
        for i in range (1,int(x)+1):
            factorial = factorial * i
    return factorial

power = input('Enter the power')
print(binomial_theorem(power))
```